# AlarmManager setRepeating()

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My program is designed to create a repeating alarm that triggers a broadcastreceiver in turn making a notification. The alarm is repeated using a user-entered interval.

For example, if i want to set the alarm to run every 10 seconds, how would I do that?

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  10000, calpendingintent);
```

Is this right? and my broadcast receiver isn't being called either for some reason.

```
public static void createAlarms(Context mcontext) {
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, alarmintervalint);
    calintent = new Intent(mcontext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    calpendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mcontext.getApplicationContext(), 12345, calintent, 0);
    am = (AlarmManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  10000, calpendingintent);
}
```

My broadcastreceiver class is not being called and Im not sure the "setRepeating()" method Im using is set correctly..

Please help!

Comment: If you still have problems I suggest you to follow this tutorial, it's really helpful : http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/ . It helped me a lot dealing with AlarmManager.

Answer (score 7):

use this code

```
  AlarmManager alarmMgr;
  PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public void startAlarmManager()
        {
             Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);

                  alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, dialogIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                  alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);

              }
        }
```

wheather you want to stop alarm

```
public void stopAlarmManager()
{          
    if(alarmMgr != null)
       alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Be Remembered dont forget to register Receiver in manifest file

```
  <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver" >
        </receiver>
```

Comment: this is nice! thanks. but my alarm will trigger a notification so do I need to make changes?

Comment: how can i reset this alarm? like suppose after 50 alarms, i want to reset the interval. can I just call this method? because when i try that now, its giving me a never ending loop between this method and the broadcastreceiver class.

Comment: Simple take one Integer variable in AlarmBroadcastReceiver , when alarm triggred increase value of that variable &  if variable == 50 then you have to call above stopAlarmManager() method.

Answer (score 3):

Use **setInexactRepeating()** instead of **setRepeating()**. When you use **setInexactRepeating()**, Android synchronizes repeating alarms from multiple apps and fires them at the same time.

This reduces the total number of times the system must wake the device, thus reducing drain on the battery. As of Android 4.4 (API Level 19), all repeating alarms are inexact.

Note that while **setInexactRepeating()** is an improvement over **setRepeating()**, it can still overwhelm a server if every instance of an app hits the server around the same time. Therefore, for network requests, add some randomness to your alarms

Answer (score -1):

you can use this. Hope it solves your problem

```
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: What is difference between Inexact and normal? And I don't want to set the interval for a day. It is a user inputed variable (integer)

Comment: Use setInexactRepeating() instead of setRepeating(). When you use setInexactRepeating(), Android synchronizes repeating alarms from multiple apps and fires them at the same time. This reduces the total number of times the system must wake the device, thus reducing drain on the battery. As of Android 4.4 (API Level 19), all repeating alarms are inexact. Note that while setInexactRepeating() is an improvement over setRepeating(), it can still overwhelm a server if every instance of an app hits the server around the same time. Therefore, for network requests, add some randomness to your alarms

Answer (score -1):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

    long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent i = new Intent(G.context, BootCompleteReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, 0, i, 0);

    G.alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
```

Comment: In the question asked, he is willing to set the repeated alarm, your solution will only trigger an alarm once.

Comment: dear friend , I will check this code again and edit it.

Comment: Thanks, that would be better as a newly learner won't get confused by this.